# Can I import a specific task from a role with dynamic name?

Tags: ansible

I have this role structure:

```
roles/
- a/
  - tasks/
    - main.yml
    - k8s.yml
 - templates/
   - mytemplate.yml.j2
- b/
  - tasks/
    - main.yml
    - k8s.yml
 - templates/
   - mytemplate.yml.j2
```

In my playbook I need to dynamically include a role, but running `k8s.yml` instead of `main.yml`. Something like this:

```
- roles:
  - "{{ rolename }}/k8s.yml"
```

There's a `include_role` module that does exactly that:

```
 - include_role:
    name: "{{ rolename }}"
    tasks_from: k8s
```

However this fails due to a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21285) that doesn't allow variables in the role `name` and will be fixed only on ansible 2.5 :(

Another approach would be to use `include_tasks`:

```
include_tasks: "roles/{{ rolename }}/tasks/k8s.yml"
```

The tasks are included and executed, but I get a failure message due to the fact that templates are not found  (ansible tries to find the templates relative to the playbook dir, not the role dir):

```
TASK [Template processing] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:    /home/myuser/myproject/mytemplate.yml.j2
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access 'mytemplate.yml.j2'\nSearched in:\n\t/home/myuser/myproject/roles/a/tasks/templates/mytemplate.yml.j2\n\t/home/myuser/myproject/roles/a/tasks/mytemplate.yml.j2\n\t/home/myuser/myproject/templates/mytemplate.yml.j2\n\t/home/myuser/myproject/mytemplate.yml.j2"}
```

I even tried to overwrite the `include_roles` module with the [patched version](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/33386) by adding it to `myproject/library/`, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Is there any way to accomplish this goal?

**EDIT:** The playbook works fine if the `rolename` variable is set on command line as an extra var, but it fails when it is set up with `set_fact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent the bug by using `hostvars`:

```
- include_role:
    name: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['rolename'] }}"
    tasks_from: k8s
```

This way I can make it work until ansible 2.5 is released